# TBB parallel_reduce - need better understanding of example from the "Developer Reference"

Tags: c++, tbb

I'm looking at the example on the [page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506154), which shows how to call the `parallel_reduce` in imperative form. Copy of this example is below:

```
struct Sum {
  float value;
  Sum() : value(0) {}
  Sum( Sum& s, split ) {value = 0;}
  void operator()( const blocked_range<float*>& r ) {
    float temp = value;
    for( float* a=r.begin(); a!=r.end(); ++a ) {
        temp += *a;
    }
    value = temp;
  }
  void join( Sum& rhs ) {value += rhs.value;}
};

float ParallelSum( float array[], size_t n ) {
  Sum total;
  parallel_reduce( blocked_range<float*>( array, array+n ),
                 total );
  return total.value;
}
```

My question is - why do we need `float temp` variable in the `operator()` body? What might happen, if summation would work directly with the `value` data member:

```
for( float* a=r.begin(); a!=r.end(); ++a ) value += *a;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work when applied directly because each instance of the class is used by one thread at the same time.

But using this variable directly might prevent compiler from vectorization of the loop. I'd go one step further with this logic by caching the r.end() because if it is not inlined properly, it can break vectorization as well. Though, it is not directly related to TBB itself, just general C++ optimization tricks.

Comment: Got it! Спасибо